# How can I tell if a UITextView text is wrapping?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uitextview

I am trying to draw a block of text with a stroke. So doing a bit of searching and experimenting seems that the way to do it is to subclass UIView and draw the text with a stroke in drawRect. The drawing code is below.

The way I have it set up, I am using a UITextView to enter the text I want interactively, then the text is passed to the UIView subclass ad drawn with a stroke.

This seems to be working perfectly. The only problem is when the return key is pressed (creating a new line), or the line wraps because it becomes too wide for the UITextView, this information is not passed, so there is no new line in my renderd (stroked) text drawn in the UIView subclass.

Any help?

Drawing code (note that theText is a property to pass the UITextView's text to):

```
    UIFont *font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:fontSize];
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0,0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [theText drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must duplicate the wrapping logic of uitextview. Ask the string how long the substring needs to be, and when it gets to long to fit its going to wrap.

You can also look at DTCoreText, a class that lets you render attributed text. However the version that mimics textviews and supports text entry costs something. In the end that cost may be worth it as duplicating a textview will take time .

Comment: Thanks David. Is that to say that there is no hidden code when the return key is pressed (\n) nor the same when the text is wrapped. Because if there was, I suppose it would simply be a matter of reading those character and passing them along.

Comment: The return key is almost for sure just that - its a single character telling the textView to go to the next line. Its the other wrapping that is most problematic for you - hypens, backspacing where a word gets shorter so the view wraps back a line. I dare say you'd be better off writing your own UITextView than try to second guess what its doing. Are you sure that the font you are using does not have strikeout characters in the Unicode space? You may be able to find or buy a font with such a thing, then you just gets a whole lot easier - just substitute characters.